# VSCode and remote debugging in Chrome Developer Tools

Tags: visual-studio-code, vscode-debugger

Are there any step by step instructions for beginners to be able to see the output of VSCode code runs in Chrome Developer Tools?

Here is what I have done:
Installed "Debugger for Chrome" 3.1.7 extension with VSCode - extension installed OK, along with Live Server 1.6.7. Launch.json file shows up as below. However, even if I restart Chrome and VSCode, I can't see any logs in Chrome Developer tools. 
Thanks!

```json
{
    "version": "0.2.0",
    "configurations": [
       {
           "type": "chrome",
           "request": "launch",
           "name": "Launch Chrome against localhost",
           "url": "http://localhost:8080",
           "webRoot": "${workspaceRoot}"
       },
       {
           "type": "chrome",
           "request": "attach",
           "name": "Attach to Chrome",
           "port": 9222,
           "webRoot": "${workspaceRoot}"
       }
    ]
}
```